# SQL Query that will migrate all Unique data from same database

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Can someone help me write a query that will copy all Unique occurences from Table1 (id_objects,tags) and put them in table 2 .Id_objects on id_objects , tags on code in table 2 and tags on title in table 3

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wish to achieve?

```
insert into table2 (id_objects, code)
    select distinct id_objects, tags from table1
```

Comment: Only tags need to be distinct , also i need to put  'tags' to other table at 'title'

Comment: putting `tags` in another table can be a separate query altogether. (plz don't mix it up with this query, it will only build confusion)

Comment: As for the other bit - can you please give a sample scenario with 2 entries in both the columns, to better understand your expectations?

Comment: Ive managed to work it out alone , thank you for help :)

Comment: Great, you should consider posting your answer that worked for you! Maybe it will help others.